# Cypress get value from within

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I've been trying to test my app by Cypress. Unfortunately, I encountered a problem with cypress..
I really want save an element that I've found in `within` method.
However, there is a problem that I can't get this element - Cypress can't save it to variable ( in my code that's it `element` variable ).

Any ideas how can I save anything that I will find in `within` to variable that is declared outside the `within` method?

I'm talking about `find` method.

[image: MyCode]

Comment: `within` is synchronous :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [as](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as.html#as-is-asynchronous)

ex:

```js
cy.get('input').as('myInput')

cy.get('@myInput').should('be.visible')
```

Comment: So.. as I understand I should rewrite it to not to use `this` at all, right?

Comment: I mean instead of using `this.wrapper` I should use `cy.get('@wrapper')`.

Comment: No, in your case instead of assigning to an element you can alias. Ex: ```this.wrapper.within(() => {
  if(tagName) {
    cy.get(`[${tagName}="${tag}"]`).as('element');
  }else {
    cy.get(tag).as('element');
  }
});
return multiple ? cy.get('@element') : cy.get('@element').first();```

Comment: There is another problem that `this.wrapper` is not a DOM element. However, when I use `cy.get('body')` instead of `this.wrapper` it works..

Comment: It looks like `this.wrapper` is not saved in constructor, or? :O

Comment: I think your constructor init before `cy` available. To solve it we should define getter such as: `get wrapper() {return cy.get('body')}`

Comment: Okay.. I found a solution. I had to replace `this.wrapper = getWrapper()` with `this.wrapper = getWrapper` and call `this.wrapper()` everywhere. Weird :D